# Terraform fails in GitLab due to cache

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, terraform, gitlab-ci, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to deploy my AWS infrastructure using **Terraform** from **GitLab CI CD Pipeline**.
I am using the GitLab managed image and it's default Terraform template.

I have configured S3 backend and it's pointing to the S3 bucket used to store the tf state file.
I had stored CI CD variables in GitLab for: **AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'** and **'S3_BUCKET'**.

Everything was working fine, until I changed the **'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID', 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'** and **'S3_BUCKET'** which was pointing to a different AWS account.

Now I am getting the following error:

> $ terraform init
> Initializing the backend...
> Backend configuration changed!
> Terraform has detected that the configuration specified for the backend
> has changed. Terraform will now check for existing state in the backends.
> Error: Error loading state:
> AccessDenied: Access Denied
> status code: 403, request id: XXXXXXXXXXXX,
> host id: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
> Terraform failed to load the default state from the "s3" backend.
> State migration cannot occur unless the state can be loaded. Backend
> modification and state migration has been aborted. The state in both the
> source and the destination remain unmodified. Please resolve the
> above error and try again.
> Cleaning up file based variables 00:00
> ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

Since this issue happened because I changed the access_key and secret_key (It was working fine from my local VS Code), **I commented out the 'cache:' block in the .gitlab-ci.yml file and it worked!**

The following is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
stages:
  - validate
  - plan
  - apply
  - destroy



image:
  name: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-build-images:terraform
  entrypoint:
    - '/usr/bin/env'
    - 'PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin'

# Default output file for Terraform plan
variables:
  PLAN: plan.tfplan
  JSON_PLAN_FILE: tfplan.json
  STATE: dbrest.tfstate

cache:
  paths:
    - .terraform



before_script:
  - alias convert_report="jq -r '([.resource_changes[]?.change.actions?]|flatten)|{\"create       \":(map(select(.==\"create\"))|length),\"update\":(map(select(.==\"update\"))|length),\"delete\":(map(select(.==\"delete\"))|length)}'"
  - terraform --version
  - terraform init



validate:
  stage: validate
  script:
    - terraform validate
  only:
    - tags


plan:
  stage: plan
  script:
    - terraform plan -out=plan_file
    - terraform show --json plan_file > plan.json
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - plan.json
    expire_in: 2 weeks
    when: on_success
    reports:
      terraform: plan.json
  only:
    - tags
  allow_failure: true 


apply:
  stage: apply
  extends: plan
  environment:
    name: production
  script:
    - terraform apply --auto-approve
  dependencies:
    - plan
  only:
    - tags
  when: manual


terraform destroy:
  extends: apply
  stage: destroy
  script:
    -  terraform destroy --auto-approve
  needs: ["plan","apply"]
  when: manual  
  only:
    - tags
```

The issue clearly happens if I don't comment out the below block. However it used to work before I made changes to the AWS access_key and secret_key.

```
#cache:
#  paths:
#    - .terraform
```

When the cache was not commented, the following was the result in the CI CI Pipeline:

[image]

**Is cache being stored anywhere? And How do I clear it?
Think it's related to GitLab.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that runner cache can be cleared off from GitLab from the UI itself.
Go to **GitLab** -> **CI CD** -> **Pipelines** and hit the '**Clear Runner Cache**' button to clear the cache.

It actually works!